# MKAnnotation Title property not found

Tags: ios, mkmapview, core-location

MKAnnotation Title property not found

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
 {
   MKAnnotationView *selectedAnnotation = (MKAnnotationView *)view.annotation;//view.annotation; // This will give the annotation.
  NSString *temp = selectedAnnotation.title;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That would be because it doesn't have a title https://developer.apple.com/reference/mapkit/mkannotationview

You want to get hold of the MKAnnotation the view is rendering for the title

https://developer.apple.com/reference/mapkit/mkannotation

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
   MKAnnotation *selectedAnnotation = (MKAnnotation *)view.annotation;//view.annotation; // This will give the annotation.
  NSString *temp = selectedAnnotation.title;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set multi pins to map put title of them in array

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
    NSUInteger index = [mapView.annotations indexOfObject:view.annotation];
    NSLog(@"index no %lu",(unsigned long)index);
    NSString *temp =__titlesArray[index];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the answer,

Take a view controller as     MyAnnotaionViewController

Then in the delegate method call that     MyAnnotaionViewController

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
 MyAnnotaionViewController *selectedAnnotation =   (MyAnnotaionViewController *)view.annotation;//view.annotation; // This will give the annotation.
 NSString *temp = selectedAnnotation.title;
}
```